# iOS Extension: can't change icon

Tags: ios, xcode, icons

I'm developing an iOS Extension (Audio Unit) and I had provided a temporary icon for my App. However, I can't change the old icon for a new final icon.

Providing/replacing all icon files in the AppIcon asset catalog changes only the icons of the app containing the extension, but not the icon of the extension itself.

I've cleaned the project, rebuilt in every way; removed asset catalogs, etc. no dice. Anyone know of a solutions?

XCode 7.3, iOS 9.3.4

Comment: Is it possible that you set the icon within `plist` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved: after installing the app with a new/higher version number (not build number) the icon was updated on the device.

Comment: Started typing this and then saw it's Bram Bos! Glad to have found a pro to ask: "Where set that icon?" Already set the app icon in Assets.xcassets, but Garageband is still showing that default AU icon. Thanks in advance for explaining how!